# how do I pass parameters to the function on onClick? (Error: 'void' is not assignable to type )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Error Message:**

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1443, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'

**Question: Why am I forced to use mouseEvent to onClick? And how do I pass parameters to the function on onClick?**

```
groups.map((group) => {
  group.fields.map((field) => {
   ...
    <button
       ///****ERROR MESSAGE HERE****///
       onClick={this.handleClickOption(group.index, 'g', field.label)}
       type="button"
       className={styles.emptyButton}
    >
```

Here is my handleClickOption call

```
  handleClickOption(connectorName: string, stepIndex: string | number, label: string): void {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(`${connectorName}.${stepIndex}.${label})]`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be invoking the `handleClickOption()` func immediately. Instead, you can pass in an anonymous function.

```
groups.map((group) => {
  group.fields.map((field) => {
   ...
    <button
       ///****ERROR MESSAGE HERE****///
       onClick={() => this.handleClickOption(group.index, 'g', field.label)}
       type="button"
       className={styles.emptyButton}
    >
```

And there is a problem with the signature of `handleClickOption()`. You might need to remove the `void` return type.

Comment: The `onClick` handler isn't called with any of those arguments (it's only called with a MouseEvent reference). So you should do: `onClick={e => this.handleClickOption(group.index, 'g', field.label)}` or better still:  `onClick={() => this.handleClickOption(group.index, 'g', field.label)}` since you're not using the MouseEvent reference

Comment: Good catch with the mistake. Removed the params.

Comment: Arror function helped